# Gettign an error as FROM keyword not found where expected in oracle even used the correct From keyword

Tags: oracle

can any one suggest where i did mistake.

```
WITH TempResult as
        (
                SELECT
                f.rbase_fmla_name as FilingName,
                f.user_comp_eff_dt, 
                f.user_rnwl_dt, 
                f.user_n_bus_dt, 
                f.pf_wkstn_oid_lng,
                f.pf_wkstn_oid_sh, 
                f.fmla_flng_u_exp_dt as expDate,
                rtrim(f.flng_origntr) ||' | '||rtrim(f.flng_lob)||' | '||rtrim(f.flng_regn) as FileTag,
                'Formula' as DisplayType, 
                null as Origin, 
                f.wkstn_oid_lng, 
                f.wkstn_oid_sh,
                CAST(f.iteration_number AS varchar(10) )||'.'||CAST(f.minor_version AS varchar(10)) as version, 
                status_indc, 
                f.status_indc as WIPStatus,
                upper(RTrim(f.rbase_fmla_name) ||'-'|| CAST(f.user_n_bus_dt AS varchar(10)) ||'-'|| CAST(f.user_comp_eff_dt as varchar(10)) ||'-'||
                CAST(f.user_rnwl_dt AS varchar(10)) ||'-'|| CAST(f.iteration_number AS
                varchar(10)) ||'-'|| rtrim(f.flng_origntr) ||' | '||rtrim(f.flng_lob)||' |
                '||rtrim(f.flng_regn)) as NameWithDates,
                v.fmla_txt ,
                v.fmla_txt_l, 
                null as rt_temp_Key, 
                null as rt_temp_fields, 
                null as rt_ri_fld, 
                null as rt_data, null as rt_key_data, 
                null as rt_ri_data, 
                null as rt_ky_cmpnnt_x_val, 
                null as standardDefault from fmla_flng_adptn f 
                inner join pmry_fmla_flng v on f.pf_wkstn_oid_sh = v.wkstn_oid_sh AND 
                f.pf_wkstn_oid_lng = v.wkstn_oid_lng
                where 1= 1 AND (rtrim(f.flng_origntr) ||' | '||rtrim(f.flng_lob)||' | '||rtrim(f.flng_regn)) = COALESCE(null, (rtrim(f.flng_origntr) ||' | '||rtrim(f.flng_lob)||' | '||rtrim(f.flng_regn)))
                and f.rbase_fmla_name like '%'|| COALESCE(null, f.rbase_fmla_name)||'%'
                union all
                SELECT
                f.rbase_rttbl_name as FilingName, 
                f.user_comp_eff_dt,
                f.user_rnwl_dt, 
                f.user_n_bus_dt, 
                f.pf_wkstn_oid_lng, 
                f.pf_wkstn_oid_sh,
                f.rt_flng_u_exp_dt as ExpDate,
                rtrim(f.flng_origntr) ||' | '||rtrim(f.flng_lob)||' | '||rtrim(f.flng_regn) as FileTag,
                (case
                 f.rt_flng_type_indc when 'C' then 'Constant Table' else 'Keyed Table' end) as DisplayType, 
                 null as Origin,
                 f.wkstn_oid_lng, 
                 f.wkstn_oid_sh,
                 CAST(f.iteration_number AS varchar(10))||'.'||CAST(f.minor_version AS varchar(10)) as version, 
                 status_indc, 
                 f.status_indc as WIPStatus,
                 upper(RTrim(f.rbase_rttbl_name) ||'-'|| CAST(f.user_n_bus_dt AS varchar(10)) ||'-'|| CAST(f.user_comp_eff_dt AS varchar(10)) ||'-'||
                 CAST(f.user_rnwl_dt as varchar(10) ) ||'-'|| CAST(f.iteration_number as
                 varchar(10)) ||'-'|| rtrim(f.flng_origntr) ||' | '||rtrim(f.flng_lob)||' |
                 '||rtrim(f.flng_regn)) as NameWithDates,null as fmla_txt ,
                 null as fmla_txt_l,
                 GetKeyStructureXml(f.pf_wkstn_oid_sh, f.pf_wkstn_oid_lng, f.llr_oid_sh, f.llr_oid_lng) as rt_temp_Key, 
                 GetRateStructureXml(f.pf_wkstn_oid_sh,f.pf_wkstn_oid_lng, f.llr_oid_sh, f.llr_oid_lng) as rt_temp_fields,
                 GetRetInfoStructureXml(f.wkstn_oid_sh, f.wkstn_oid_lng, f.llr_oid_sh, f.llr_oid_lng) as rt_ri_fld,
                 GetRtDataXml(f.pf_wkstn_oid_sh, f.pf_wkstn_oid_lng) as rt_data,
                 GetRateKeyDataXml(f.pf_wkstn_oid_sh, f.pf_wkstn_oid_lng) as rt_key_data,
                 GetRateRiDataXml(f.wkstn_oid_sh, f.wkstn_oid_lng) as rt_ri_data,
                 GetRateRtKeyCmpntDataXml(f.pf_wkstn_oid_sh, f.pf_wkstn_oid_lng) as rt_ky_cmpnnt_x_val,
                 GetStandadrdDefaultDataXml(f.pf_wkstn_oid_sh, f.pf_wkstn_oid_lng) as standardDefault  from rt_flng_adptn f
                 where 1= 1 AND 
                 rtrim(f.flng_origntr) ||' | '||rtrim(f.flng_lob)||' | '||rtrim(f.flng_regn) = COALESCE(null,rtrim(f.flng_origntr) ||' | '||rtrim(f.flng_lob)||' | '||rtrim(f.flng_regn)) 
                 and f.rbase_rttbl_name like '%'|| COALESCE(null,f.rbase_rttbl_name)||'%'
        ),
        UnionTable as
        (
                SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NameWithDates) as RowNum,
                FilingName, 
                user_comp_eff_dt, 
                user_rnwl_dt,
                user_n_bus_dt, 
                pf_wkstn_oid_lng, 
                pf_wkstn_oid_sh, 
                expDate,
                FileTag,
                DisplayType, 
                Origin, 
                wkstn_oid_lng, 
                wkstn_oid_sh, 
                version, 
                status_indc,
                WIPStatus,
                NameWithDates , 
                fmla_txt, 
                fmla_txt_l, 
                rt_temp_Key, 
                rt_temp_fields,
                rt_ri_fld, 
                rt_data, 
                rt_key_data, 
                rt_ri_data, 
                rt_ky_cmpnnt_x_val, 
                standardDefault
                from TempResult
        )
        SELECT *
        FROM UnionTable
        WHERE RowNum > 0
        AND RowNum < 11
        AND RowNum = 10;
```

getting an error as:

ERROR at line 73:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Answer (score 3):

`rownum` is a reserved word, do not use it as alias.

```
SQL> select 1 as rownum from dual;
select 1 as rownum from dual
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

The error message even tells you where the problem is , line 73:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NameWithDates) as RowNum,
```